# Mercurial: How to restore file names removed with "hg rm -A"?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Okay, so I really got ahead of myself here.

After moving a number of files around, renaming some, and deleting a bunch more, I ended up with a large number of files in `hg status` with an exclamation point (along with numerous question marks). I ran `hg rm -A` to remove all the files that no longer existed.

Then I realized I should have used `hg addremove` to track the files that were just moved, not deleted. Oops.

But I hadn't committed anything yet, and `hg status` showed all those "missing" files with an R now. So I ran `hg revert` thinking that would restore everything to the way it was. I could even see where it said `Undeleting file /path/to/xyz` for each file that I wanted to restore (I wasn't worried about restoring the files themselves, of course, just the file paths).

But instead of a big list of files with exclamation points, those "removed" file references are simply gone. They're not listed in `hg status`, they're not in the file system (obviously), and they're not listed in any recent commit.

What's going on here?

- Why would all those file references just disappear from the repo without a commit?
- How can I get those file references back so I can actually track them like I wanted to?

*I'm pretty rusty with DVCS, I guess. I realize now I should have been using `hg move` for these operations, but that doesn't help my current situation, does it? :)*

Comment: Make sure that the currently checked-out revision is one which should contain those files you worry about

Comment: Does a clean clone and update of the repo contain the files?